# How to construct such a functional-programming tool in Python?

Tags: python, function, recursion, functional-programming

I want a function named `times()`, in order to make:

`times(func,2)` equivalent to `lambda x:func(func(x))`

and `times(func,5)` equivalent to `lambda x:func(func(func(func(func(x)))))`

Is there such a tool in Python? What would the code looks like if I want to write it by myself?

Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'd suggest to call this `power()`, since this is actually the `n`th power of a function.  There is no such thing in the standard library, but you can easily implement it yourself:

```
def power(f, n):
    def wrapped(x):
        for i in range(n):
            x = f(x)
        return x
    return wrapped
```

Comment: I would give this +100 if I could. So elegant!

Comment: I'm just wondering whether there's a **recursive** instead of **iterative** way to do this..

Answer (score 5):

Thanks, Sven

I found a recursive way to do that, but yours looks more pythonic:

```
def power(func, n):
    def lazy(x, i=n):
        return func(lazy(x, i-1)) if i > 0 else x
    return lazy    

>>> power(lambda x:x*2,3)(9)
72
>>> power(lambda x:x*2,2)(9)
36
>>> power(lambda x:x*2,1)(9)
18
>>> power(lambda x:x*2,0)(9)
9
```

And a way implemented with decorator:

```
def powerize(n):
    def wrapped(func):
        def newfunc(*args):
            return power(func,n)(*args)
        return newfunc
    return wrapped

@powerize(3)
def double_3(x):
    return x*2

>>> double_3(8)
64
```